# How to create a new folder when taking a photo from custom camera application?

Tags: android

Right now, I finished with my custom camera application that will save the picture that I took into sdcard. But I want to put these pictures in a folder which will be create when you took your first photo.

Working step:
Start my application > took a photo > check for the folder to stored in > if sdcard already have that folder then stored the photo inside the folder but if it doesn't have a folder then create new one > stop

something like this. Hope you understand what I mean, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File mFile=new File("/sdcard/photos/newfolder");
mFile.mkdir();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Well may I ask another question, Are there any way to set the size of the photo that were taken by this camera like every photo will constantly be 256x256 in size. Thanks again.

Comment: how to create folder inside assets folder.

Comment: Do NOT use hard-coded words. My phone uses `Pictures` not `photos`. please use API-provided one. `final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + "YOUR_DIRECTORY_NAME" + File.separator);`

Answer (score 1):

Just before saving your file, simply create all the directory structure, the mkdirs method will do the necessary work if necessary.

[new File("/sdcard/photos/newfolder").mkdirs()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29)

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you need to mark it as accepted (using the check mark on the left of it).